# Pass payload into Hapi 17 Redirect

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I have a route set up to switch locale. It should redirect the user back to the page they were on. I pass the locale in via a param. I then do some database stuff. I need to send the output of that query on to the redirect page. This is how I'm trying to do it... it doesn't work. How do I pass the data in?

```
    <!-- language: lang-js -->
   ...    
    method: "GET",
        path: "/locale/{locale}",
        options: {
            async handler(request, h) {
                const foo = (x) => {
                //.... get stuff from db etc etc
                return 'blah'
                };
                const message = await foo(request.params.locale);

            // want to attach message to response so 
            // I can use it in the redirected route
            return h.response({message: 'foo'}).redirect(request.query.redirect);
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get what you are trying to do, I would have used [server.ext()](https://hapijs.com/api#-serverextevents) with the onRequest events.

This way, your request would have trigger your function before hitting the handler.

Comment: Put the foo function inside server.ext() and add some logic so it only runs if the locale param is present?

Comment: It will trigger at any incoming request, you have to filter those... it’s this way that you craft a middleware with hapi. I must admit that I’ve never done that and that I don’t completely get what you are trying to do, but it worth a try for sure

Comment: I just remember an other solution that might be more convenient. It’s base on the ‘pre handler’ principle (https://hapijs.com/api#-routeoptionspre) Using this, you would be able to choose on which route you want to trigger the fooBar function

Comment: I tried pre and couldn't get it to work in this context. In the end I wrote the output of foo to a session... I then read the session in the redirect route - and wipe it. So the locale route sets a session... the redirect route reads the session, then wipes it and so on